# Manera correcta de crear una biblioteca en c

Tags: c, librería

Estoy en un curso de programación en lenguaje c, y llegue a una sección donde empezaremos a separar las funciones del programa principal creando nuestras propias librerías. La guía del curso explica que hay que crear un archivo ".h" con solo las declaraciones de las funciones, y luego otro archivo ".c" con el código de las funciones.

Pero "googleando" acerca del tema, encuentro que es posible hacer los dos pasos anteriores dentro de un archivo ".h".

A manera de ejemplo, ¿Podrian explicarme con el siguiente programa? (El mismo que se uso de ejemplo en el curso, pero arreglado a mi manera, la cual funciono).

Este es el contenido del archivo principal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "primo.h"

int main() {
    int num;

    printf("Introduce un numero entero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\nEl numero %d", num);

    if (primo(num))
        printf("es primo.\n");
    else
        printf(" no es primo.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Y este el contenido del archivo "primo.h"

```
#include <math.h>

int primo(int numero);

int primo(int numero) {
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(numero); i++) {
        if (numero%i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

El archivo `.h` debería contener solo la declaración (cabecera) de la función, es decir:

```
/* Contenido de primo.h */    
int primo(int numero);
```

El código de la función en sí, debería estar en otro fichero, por ejemplo `primo.c`:

```
/* Contenido de primo.c */
#include <math.h>
#include "primo.h"

int primo(int numero) {
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(numero); i++) {
        if (numero%i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Finalmente tendrías tu programa `principal.c` que haría uso de esa función:

```
/* Contenido de principal.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "primo.h"

int main() {
    int num;

    printf("Introduce un numero entero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\nEl numero %d", num);

    if (primo(num))
        printf("es primo.\n");
    else
        printf(" no es primo.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Ahora que tienes el código repartido en varios ficheros ¿cómo se compila?

Podrías compilar "todo de una vez" con un comando como el siguiente:

```
gcc -o ejecutable primos.c principal.c
```

pero una buena práctica (por razones que explicaré luego) es compilar cada fuente `.c` por separado, para generar su correspondiente *código objeto* y después enlazar todos los códigos objeto en un solo ejecutable, así:

```
gcc -c primos.c                # Produce un primos.o
gcc -c principal.c             # Produce un principal.o
gcc -o ejecutable primos.o principal.o
```

Fíjate que en la última instrucción "juntamos" los diferentes `.o` para crear el ejecutable final. En las dos primeras instrucciones en cambio nos limitamos a compilar por separado cada `.c` sin pretender crear el ejecutable todavía (la opción `-c` es para eso). Sin  esa opción, la primera línea fallaría porque diría que falta la función `main()`, y la segunda línea fallaría porque diría que falta la función `primo()`.

Con la opción `-c` el compilador se limita a verificar que la llamada a `primo()` es correcta (y para eso necesita conocer su declaración, por eso la tenemos en un `.h`), pero no *resuelve* la llamada del todo (no completa a qué dirección de memoria hay que llamar, porque no lo sabe, porque el código de esa función no está disponible para él). Deja esa labor al montador de enlaces, que es lo que ejecutamos en la última línea.

Pensarás que esto es mucho más complicado que la opción de hacerlo todo en una sola línea, pero en realidad son equivalentes, ya que cuando pones varios `.c` en la línea de `gcc`, éste hace las dos fases (primero compila cada `.c` para generar un `.o` y luego los enlaza todos), con la diferencia de que borra los `.o` intermedios.

Y si son equivalentes, entonces ¿a qué complicarse tanto haciendo la compilación separada de forma manual? Pues esto cobra sentido cuando tu aplicación empieza a ser enorme, compuesta por docenas (quizás centenares) de ficheros, y tarda un montón en compilar. Si tras haber compilado los primeros 80 ficheros, hay un error en el fichero 81, la compilación se abortará y el ejecutable no podrá ser creado. Te tocará corregir el bug de ese fichero y reintentar la compilación. Con la opción de compilar "de una vez" toda la aplicación, volverías a recompilar los 80 ficheros iniciales. Esto en realidad es supérfluo, pues ya sabíamos que estaban bien. Compilando cada uno por separado, cuando modifiques uno de los `.c` sólo necesitarás recompilar ese, y después enlazar de nuevo. El paso del enlazado es muchísimo más rápido que el de compilado, y de este modo se ahorra mucho tiempo durante el desarrollo.

Naturalmente en una aplicación compuesta de cientos de ficheros puede resultar muy difícil seguir la pista de cuáles has modificado y cuáles no, cuáles es necesario recompilar y cuáles estaban bien, y más si hay fichero que dependen de otros, de modo que si recompilas uno hay que recompilar también otros. Para automatizar esta tarea se usa la herramienta `make` y  los `Makefile`.

Finalmente, si el código contenido en uno de tus `.c`  (por ejemplo `primo.c`) va a ser usado a menudo por diferentes aplicaciones, puedes querer crear una *librería* (o biblioteca) con él. Una librería es un archivo que junta muchos `.o`, ya compilados.

Para esto se usa la utlidad `ar`, por ejemplo así:

```
ar rcs libprimos.a primo.o
```

(observa que antes habrás tenido que hacer `gcc -c primo.c`, para obtener `primo.o`).

Ese comando dará lugar al archivo `libprimos.a` que contiene el código máquina (ya compilado) de la función `primos()`. La idea es que ahora podrías suministrar a otros desarrolladores estos dos ficheros: `libprimos.a` y `primo.h`, de modo que ellos puedan usar tu función *sin necesitar su código fuente*.

Para usar tu función deberían hacer el `#include "primo.h"` en su programa (para que el compilador pueda verificar que se llama a la función con los parámetros adecuados), y compilar su programa añadiendo la opción `-l` para especificar librerías extra. El nombre de la librería sería el del fichero `.a`, pero quitándole la parte `lib` inicial. Es decir:

```
gcc programa.c -lprimos -L.
```

La opción `-lprimos` hace que el montador de enlaces busque un fichero llamado `libprimos.a` y dentro de él el código de las funciones que necesita para completar el ejecutable. La opción `-L.` le dice que busque ese archivo en la carpeta actual (se podrían poner varias rutas separadas por `:`)

Answer (score 1):

**RESPUESTA CORTA:**

El **preprocesador** es un primer paso separado en la compilación. La directiva `#include` se utiliza para incluir el contenido de un archivo durante la compilación

Frecuentemente existen varias líneas `#include` al principio de un archivo fuente, para incluir proposiciones `#define` y declaraciones `extern` comunes, o para tener acceso a la declaración del prototipo de una función de la biblioteca estándar.

Por convención, los archivos de encabezado utilizan la extensión `.h` (del Inglés header).

Sintácticamente, debido a que es sólo una sustitución de texto, el programa que presentas no presentará un problema para el compilador, considerando también que sólo estás incluyendo el archivo de encabezado en un solo archivo fuente (archivo principal).

Sin embargo, agregar definiciones de funciones en un archivo de encabezado no es recomendable debido a que no podrá ser usado en ambientes en donde incluyas el encabezado en múltiples archivos, debido a que existirán multiples definiciones de la misma función (una por cada unidad compilable en donde se incluya el encabezado).

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo exactamente tu pregunta, pero ese ejemplo esta bien, lo que pasa con C es que cuenta con un precompilador, que convierte ese `#include` en **TODO** el contenido del otro archivo. Es como que tú estés copiando todo ese código de "primo.h" en esa línea, entonces todo funciona correctamente y es mucho más elegante para que este bien bonito.